# Unity XR menu missing options

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xdKF.png)

When I start an XR project, some options are missing in the GameObject -> XR Menu. All the templates I have downloaded have this issue.

[Sample reference of what it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsngX.png)

I already have the XR rig and the Main Camera is already inside it. What could be the issue? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't have XR Interaction Manager installed. Go to:

**Window > Package Manager**

Then look in the upper left and select **Unity Registry** from the packages drop down menu (as seen on the screenshot). Then scroll all the way down and **XR Interaction Toolkit** should be one of the last packages on the list. Click on it and click install and agree to all the prompts.

Now go back to **GameObject > XR** and all options should appear now.

[image: Screenshot of package manager menu.]

I know you posted this a while ago, but I hope this helps someone else.